# Espresso, how to scroll to bottom and IDLE state of recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am learning UI testing with Espresso. I want to test scrolling of recycler view to bottom and only then load next page from view model and pass it recycler view.

I have following onScrollListener in my fragment:

```
private fun setupOnScrollListener() {
        recyclerViewApi.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

                val isRecyclerViewBottom = !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) &&
                        newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE

                if (isRecyclerViewBottom) {
                    downloadNextPage()
                }
            }
        })
    }

private fun downloadNextPage() {
        showProgressBar(true)
        viewModel.getNextMovies()
    }
```

When I test it manually with `Log.d()` it works great.

**My question is**: How to use Espresso (or maybe different API, if you know better than Espresso) to scroll recycler view to this state:
`isRecyclerViewBottom = !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`,
so my `downloadNextPage()` will be invoked and test function will pull more data.

My test function:

```
@Test
    fun scrollToBottom_isNextPageLoaded(){
        every { repository.getApiMovies(any(), any()) } returns
                Flowable.just(Resource.success(moviesList1_5)) andThen
                Flowable.just(Resource.success(moviesList1_10))

        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<ApiFragment>(factory = fragmentsFactory)
        //first 5 items are in view, so I go to the last item (index 4)
        recyclerView.perform(scrollToPosition<ViewHolder>(4))
        recyclerView.perform(swipeDown())
       //Below doesn't make any difference
        Thread.sleep(1000L) 

        verify(exactly = 2) { repo.getApiMovies(any(), any()) }
    }
```

I use Robolectric, Mockk, Espresso. I have mocked here repository class, which is passed to constructor of ViewModelFactory, which is passed to constructor of the ApiFragment.

Message from JUnit:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: ApiRepository(repo#4).getApiMovies(any(), any())). 
One matching call found, but needs at least 2 and at most 2 calls
Call: ApiRepository(repo#4).getApiMovies(Top Rated, 1)
```

It is not my first test function. Everything else works great. I just don't know how to make Espresso to go to bottom of recycler view and 'pull up' bottom edge of it to call `downloadNextPage()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Espresso Recyclerview scroll to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915073/espresso-recyclerview-scroll-to-end)

Comment: @agoff, I have seen it. It didn't help, but below I have placed my sollution for it. Maybe I should write it here, in comments, to make it more visible for this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have just found a sollution. I changed `recyclerView.perform(swipeDown())` to `recyclerView.perform(swipeUp())`.